70s or 80s sci-fi book, boy has secateur hand
I'm looking to identify a sci-fi book I read a few times as a tween / young teen in the 80s. Set in the future where jobs are predetermined and the body is manipulated accordingly. The main character is a young man who is a gardener, and his (probably left) hand is shaped into secateurs (pruning shears). The cover art had him with his love interest, and he had the secateur hand on her shoulder, I think.
The only other thing I remember is that the weather could be controlled, so it only rained at night.

The Others by Alison Prince.

The cover doesn't show the secateur hand, but the description does mention it:

Ergo, with his secateur fingers and his green twine hair, can see no way out of the Underhill system, designed for the privileged Others of Air City. But by a freak of fate he meets Wenti, a girl who comes from the Others, but is troubled by the injustice of the system they have created.
Falling in love with Wenti makes Ergo's dream of creating a more equal world seem almost possible. But the dangers are terrible. Will Dr Klops use his lethal powers against Ergo's mother? Is the cool Inspector Kanchu of Air City playing a double game?
Ergo is plunged into a fight for his life, and for the survival of everything he values. In this fast-moving adventure story, set in a post-nuclear-holocaust age, Alison Prince captures the horror, and humour, of this new world and has made Ergo a hero of universal appeal.


"The cover doesn't show the secateur hand" - this makes me wonder: With both hands of his visible on the cover, where is the secateur hand?

@O.R.Mapper I think it's his right hand.  Look closely at the shape of the thumb and the index finger, especially the fingertips.

I can't find a higher res image of the cover, but the right thumb and forefinger do look a little odd.

It looks like it's not strictly a secateur hand but just the right thumb and pointer finger. They're both long (especially the thumb) and especially pointed, and neither appears to have a nail.

It wouldn't be the first time the cover artist didn't read the story.

Dude looks like Shatner with a wig
